# Regular expressions in R to get the date

Tags: r, regex

What could be the better solution to get the date only, it is a tag of a webpage.
I hope someone could help me.

The patterns is this value in many pages "publishedAtDate":"2020-02-07"

I would like to have the next outcome:
2020-02-07

I am using this code:

```
art_publishdate<-regexpr("publishedAtDate\":\"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\"", thepage)
```

but the result include many backslashes.

```
[1] "publishedAtDate\":\"2020-02-07\""
```

Thank you

Comment: See https://rextester.com/EITD8645, use `str_match(a, 'publishedAtDate":"([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})"')[,2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to just pick out the numbers and format them `as.Date`.

```
as.Date(gsub("\\D", "\\1", '"publishedAtDate":"2020-02-07\"'), format="%Y%m%d")
# [1] "2020-02-07"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to capture the output.

Using `gsub` we remove everything till a colon (`:`) is encountered.

```
string <- '"publishedAtDate":"2020-02-07"'
gsub('.*:|"', '', string)
#[1] "2020-02-07"
```

Or using `sub` we can extract date pattern.

```
sub('.*?(\\d+-\\d+-\\d+).*', '\\1', string)
#[1] "2020-02-07"
```

Comment: @Fernando Looks like the string have quotes (`"`) in them. The vertical bar is `OR` in regex meaning remove everything till colon (`.*:`) OR quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `str_extract` from the `stringr` package:

```
str_extract(string, "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}")
[1] "2020-02-07"
```

Alternatively, the date can be extracted thus:

```
str_extract(string, "[0-9-]+")
[1] "2020-02-07"
```

Another alternative is using positive look-behind (which encodes the instruction "Match if you see on the left...") as well as a negated character class `[^"]`, which excludes the quote mark but no other character:

```
str_extract(string, '(?<=:")[^"]*')
[1] "2020-02-07"
```